# how to display all checked check boxes instead of just the last one selected

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra, erb

[namesex page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZrV3.png)

[final page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVzAu.png)

I want it display all my checked check boxes instead of the last one selected
excuse the `final.erb` the `fistname`, `lastname` works and so does `sirname` I just wanted to see if I could get all my checkboxes to work

app.rb

```
require "sinatra"

get '/' do 
    erb :namesex
end

post '/namesex' do 
    firstname = params[:firstname]
    lastname = params[:lastname]
    sirname = params[:sirname]
    pizzacrust = params[:pizzacrust]
    toppings = params[:toppings]
    redirect '/final?firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&sirname=' + sirname + '&pizzacrust=' + pizzacrust + '&toppings=' + toppings
end

get '/final' do 
    firstname = params[:firstname]
    lastname = params[:lastname]
    sirname = params[:sirname]
    pizzacrust = params[:pizzacrust]
    toppings = params[:toppings]
    erb :final, :locals => {:firstname => firstname, :lastname => lastname, :sirname => sirname, :pizzacrust => pizzacrust, :toppings => toppings}
end
```

namesex.erb

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pic.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

input[type=radio]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h3><font color="blue">Zacharys Pizza</h3>

<div>
  <form method="post" action="namesex">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="sir name">sir name</label>
    <select id="sirname" name="sirname">
      <option value="mr">mr</option>
      <option value="mrs">mrs</option>
      <option value="miss">miss</option>
    </select>

    <label for="pizza crust">pizza crust</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="pizzacrust" value="thin"> thin    <input type="radio" name="pizzacrust" value="deep dish"> deep dish
    <br>

    <label for="toppings">toppings</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" checked="cheese" unchecked=""> cheese <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="peporoni"> peporoni <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" checked="sausage" unchecked=""> sausage <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="fruit"> fruit
    <input type="hidden" name="toppings" value="nothing">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

final.erb

```
<div>
    <%= toppings %>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking because I know see you've asked a duplicate or near duplicate of this a few hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

If I open my repl (I use pry, IRB is always available too) and put in the following lines I will get the same error:

```
"" + nil
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
from (pry):1:in `+'
```

One (at least) of the variables on line 30 is `nil`

For a bit of simple debugging, try the following:

```
firstname = params[:firstname]
warn "firstname = #{firstname}"
```

Until you find the culprit. Longer term, you should always make sure that a variable can't be in a state it shouldn't be, and that it should reach a part of the code where it is used when it's in an unusable state.

First and foremost that means checking variables when they're set, e.g.

```
firstname = params.fetch :firstname, "FIRSTNAME"
```

But this is a web app so you shouldn't set a default for a form like that unless really intended, you should add some checking in the form using HTLM validations and some javascript validations too.

Then on in the server side app (Sinatra):

```
error FirstnameNotSet do
  'So what happened was...' + env['sinatra.error'].message
end

# snip…

firstname = params[:firstname]
raise FirstnameNotSet if firstname.nil?
```

Or you could have a conditional that returned different results based on whether you'd supplied valid information or not. This technique works well with AJAX.

```
firstname = params[:firstname]
# do all the others too
[firstname, lastname].each_with_object([]) do |variable,obj|
   obj << build_json_error_message(variable)
end
if obj.empty?
  erb :pizza
else
  halt 200, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, json obj.join
end
```

Or something like that. It wouldn't be like that but something along those lines.

That should get you fixed and started on a better course of action.

Comment: Alright I thank you for the help I put the name all the checkbooks the same and then moved from there but how can I get it to display all checked option instead of just the last on selected in my final.erb

Comment: @zacharyedgell Edit your question with a screenshot showing what you have, and what you want.

Comment: I got the code update to what it is now and got pictures uploaded and the description and title changed

Comment: What's the output for `warn "toppings = #{toppings.inspect}"`? That'll tell you if the app is receiving all the checkbox data correctly.